# mat-form-field is red even though there are no errors

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-material

I have a `mat-form-field` that is used to confirm the user's password:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput required placeholder="Gentag password" [type]="hidePassword ? 'password' : 'text'"
    formControlName="confirmPassword" [errorStateMatcher]="passwordMatcher">
  <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hidePassword = !hidePassword">{{hidePassword ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}
  </mat-icon>
  <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.hasError('mismatch') && !registerForm.hasError('required', 'confirmPassword')">De to passwords matcher ikke</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.hasError('required', 'confirmPassword')">Bekræft venligst passwordet</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is that `errorStateMatcher` that I'm using:

```js
class PasswordErrorStateMathcer implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl, form: import("@angular/forms").FormGroupDirective | import("@angular/forms").NgForm): boolean {
    return !!((control && control.touched && control.parent && control.parent.invalid) || (form.submitted));
  }
}
```

The two `mat-errors` are working as expected, but when the errors are gone, the field stays red as if it still has an error:

[image]

And here you can see the object printed in the console, where it says that it is valid:

[image]

This is how I created the `FormGroup`:

```js
this.registerForm = this.builder.group({
      firstName: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      lastName: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}([._-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})*@[a-zA-Z]{2,}([.-]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})*[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}"),
      Validators.maxLength(40)]],
      checkboxGroup: new FormGroup({
        adminCheckbox: new FormControl(false),
        proCheckbox: new FormControl(false),
        researcherCheckbox: new FormControl(false),
        datamanagerCheckbox: new FormControl(false),
      }, this.checkboxValidator),
      password: ["", [Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      confirmPassword: [""]}, { validator: this.confirmPasswordValidator, });
  }
```

And here is my `confirmPasswordValidator`:

```js
  confirmPasswordValidator(group: FormGroup) {
    let pass = group.controls.password.value;
    let confirmPass = group.controls.confirmPassword.value;

    return pass === confirmPass ? null : { mismatch: true };
  }
```

Why does it stay red?

Comment: Stackblitz example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ErrorStateMatcher checks for the parent-form status ,

```
return !!((control && control.touched && control.parent && control.parent.invalid) || (form.submitted));
```

Make sure the parent form is valid or otherwise it is submitted.

To remove the errors after entering valid data, change your ErrorStateMatcher function

```
 return !!((control && control.touched && control.invalid) || (form.submitted));
```

Comment: This solved my problem, and it makes sense. However, I was aware that it checked the parent, and I'm pretty sure I checked yesterday that the field was still red even after the parent was valid, which is no longer the case... Anyway, thanks.